# Inheritance reflection in tags

Tags: c++

I'm working on kind of publisher/subscriber block. Subscribers would subscribe messages by tag(s). The messages in the system are organized in hierarchy, so I'd like the tags reflect the hierarchy. I've made a small piece of code, how I'd like to see the system

```
class TMsg {};

class TMsg1: public TMsg {};

class TMsg2: public TMsg {};

template<class T>
struct tag {};

template<>
struct tag<TMsg1>: public tag<TMsg> {};

template<>
struct tag<TMsg2>: public tag<TMsg> {};


template<class T>
void processMessage(T &t) {
    tag<T> ti;
    procMsgImpl(ti);
}

void procMsgImpl(tag<TMsg>&) {
    std::cout << "f" << std::endl;
}

void procMsgImpl(tag<TMsg1>&) {
    std::cout << "f1" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    TMsg t;
    TMsg1 t1;
    TMsg2 t2;

    processMessage(t);
    processMessage(t1);
    processMessage(t2);
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to avoid in the snippet is explicit definition the inheritance of tags `struct tag<TMsg1>: public tag<TMsg> {};`, if the TMsg is a base class of TMsg1, I'd like the tags keep this information implicitly.

Comment: somewhere you have to make it explicit who is base of what. What do you want to write if not `struct tag<TMsg1>: public tag<TMsg> {};` ?

Comment: I really don't recommend it (which is why I won't show an example) but this could be solved using macros. I don't recommend it because it hides a lot from the readers (and future maintainers) of the code, which is bad.

Comment: By the way, what you're doing now with the tags seems wrong, as you use *both* specialization and inheritance. Use specialization only.

Comment: @tobi303 I'd like to avoid this definition because it repeat the same idea, if the classes are inherited one from the another I want the tags of the classes do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you? The idea is to make your TMsg classes inherit from a wrapper and have a generic tag:

```
#include <iostream>

// use this as a wrapper
template <class B>
struct base
: public B {

    using base_type = B;
};

class TMsg {};

// inherit from the wrapper
class TMsg1: public base<TMsg> {};

// inherit from the wrapper
class TMsg2: public base<TMsg> {};

// generic tag
template<class T>
struct tag
: public tag<typename T::base_type>{};

// full specialization for the base class
template <>
struct tag<TMsg> {};

template<class T>
void processMessage(T &t) {
    tag<T> ti;
    procMsgImpl(ti);
}

void procMsgImpl(tag<TMsg>&) {
    std::cout << "f" << std::endl;
}

void procMsgImpl(tag<TMsg1>&) {
    std::cout << "f1" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    TMsg t;
    TMsg1 t1;
    TMsg2 t2;

    processMessage(t);
    processMessage(t1);
    processMessage(t2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, trying to adopt it for multiple inheritance

Comment: @Anton: you may want to use a std::tuple then to store all base classes in that case. It is certainly possible if that is really what you want to achieve. If you are happy with the answer, please consider accepting it :) Good luck!

Comment: @Anton The [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is a commonly used solution for that problem.